# What does "We've been fooled by our tool" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, jokes

Today, I watched the TED video "Chip Conley: Measuring what makes life worthwhile".

In the video, the speaker quoted an Abe Maslow saying:

> If the only tool you have is a hammer, everything starts to look like
> a nail.

After that, he says, "We've been fooled by our tool." In the next scene, he says, "Excuse that expression," and audience laugh.

I cannot understand why they laughed then.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They laugh because 'tool' is a slang word meaning 'penis', so the pithy phrase *we've been fooled by our tool* sounds like it could have a secondary sexual meaning. It's not an extremely clever joke, just a simple bit of fun.

Comment: thank you for answer! Is it normal slang in local?

Comment: Yes, it's a common slang word. Many native speakers would know it.

Comment: Also, in Britain, the word 'tool' can be applied to a man considered to be ridiculous or foolish,  with the same 'penis' meaning as 'prick', 'dick', 'knob', etc.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Indeed! As well as the classic, though spatially more circumscribed, 'bell-end'.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey it's the same in the US, though I never thought there was any connection between those two meanings until now.

Answer (score 0):

"tool" means a mans "penis", as mentioned here in the dictionary:

> 3. vulgar slang
>
>    a man's penis.
>
>    - a stupid, irritating, or contemptible man.
>          "that guy is
>      such a tool"

So his saying:

> We've been fooled by our tool.

That's just a joke, like we've been fooled by that.